# f:convertDateTime support for Java8 LocalDate / LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, jsf, java-8, jsf-2.2

The JSF Core Tag [f:convertDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/convertDateTime.html) can format [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects. The Date class has many deprecated methods and with Java 8 come new classes to present local dates and times: [LocalDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and [LocalDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

[f:convertDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/convertDateTime.html) can not format [LocalDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) nor [LocalDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Does anybody know, if there is an equivalent to the JSF core tag convertDateTime that can deal with LocalDateTime objects? Is support planned for a future release, or are alternative tags available?

Comment: Until it's supported you can use a converter.

Comment: The replacement for `java.util.Date` (which is NOT deprecated - by the way) is `java.time.Instant`, not `LocalDate` or other *local* types.

Comment: "*The `Date` class has been deprecated for ages.*" - untrue. Although the most of the methods of the `Date` class have already been deprecated, the class itself has not been deprecated yet and is still available for use. You can always create a custom converter in JSF for any of your use-cases.

Comment: I tried to improve the question. Thanks for correcting me on the deprecation fact.

Comment: Sure the date class is full of deprecated methods. But the existing f:convertDateTime doesn't make use of any of those deprecated methods, yet your question somehow implies that and that's not really nice. In any case, JSF 2.3 will require Java 8, so that creates room for a new standard converter for Java 8 time API.

Comment: [JSF 2.3](https://javaserverfaces.github.io/docs/2.3/javadocs/javax/faces/convert/DateTimeConverter.html#setType-java.lang.String-) supports the new types `localDate`, `localDateTime`, `localTime`, `offsetTime`, `offsetDateTime`, and `zonedDateTime` to support the Java 8 time API. But keep in mind when using these new types that the converter attribute `timeZone` is ignored because the new time API has everything it needs to determine the correct time zone! See also [What's new in JSF 2.3?](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/jsf-23.html#1370)

Comment: I made the experience now myself - even in JSF 2.3 the support for java.time seems to be somewhat limited... or weird at least for me.

Comment: First Instant is NOT supported but the other types ... but you have to specify them. Why that? Also the timezone parameter is ignored. Thats sad because I want to display the dates for different time zones. Lost some hours and reverted all back to good old Date.

Answer (score 11):

Just write your own Converter and extend the `javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter` - that way you can Reuse all the attributes that `<f:convertDateTime>` supports. Also it will take care of Localization too. Unfortunately it's a bit more complicated to write a Converter with Attributes.

**Create component**
First write your own Converter that extends `javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter` - just let the super-calls do all the work (including locale-stuff) and convert the result from/to LocalDate.

```
@FacesConverter(value = LocalDateConverter.ID)
public class LocalDateConverter extends DateTimeConverter {
    public static final String ID = "com.example.LocalDateConverter";

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String value) {
        Object o = super.getAsObject(facesContext, uiComponent, value);

        if (o == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (o instanceof Date) {
            Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(((Date) o).getTime());
            return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("value=%s could not be converted to a LocalDate, result super.getAsObject=%s", value, o));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return super.getAsString(facesContext, uiComponent,value);
        }

        if (value instanceof LocalDate) {
            LocalDate lDate = (LocalDate) value;
            Instant instant = lDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
            Date date = Date.from(instant);
            return super.getAsString(facesContext, uiComponent, date);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("value=%s is not a instanceof LocalDate", value));
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a file `LocalDateConverter-taglib.xml` in `META-INF`:

```
<facelet-taglib version="2.2"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd">

    <namespace>http://example.com/LocalDateConverter</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>convertLocalDate</tag-name>
        <converter>
            <converter-id>com.example.LocalDateConverter</converter-id>
        </converter>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

And lastly, register the taglib in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/META-INF/LocalDateConverter-taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**Usage**
To use the new Tag in your JSF-Page add the new Taglib `xmlns:ldc="http://example.com/LocalDateConverter"` and  use the tag:

```
<ldc:convertLocalDate type="both" dateStyle="full"/>
```

Comment: Would be better if you target JSF 2.x Facelets, not Facelets 1.x. You're otherwise confusing JSF 2.x starters with old/deprecated ways.

Comment: But that's the way the newer JSF implementation should have worked... Looks like a good solution - better than the JSF 2.3 internal one

Comment: JSF 2.3 now supports `LocalDate` out of the box : `<h:outputText value="#{yourBean.yourLocalDateVar}" >
 <f:convertDateTime type="localDate" dateStyle="long" locale="#{yourBean.yourLocale}" />
</h:outputText>`