# Custom converter for primefaces calendar will never be called

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml, converters

I have created a custom converter for converting from and to org.joda.time.LocalDate for primefaces calendar component. Unfortunately my converter will never be invoked (annotated like below) or even when I try to register my converter in faces-config(for that I've removed all annotations from the custom converter). Instead I get an Exception that java.util.Date cannot be converted to LocalDate.

I don't want to configure the converter as a tag attribute. Instead the converter should be automatically fetched and used for conversion to and from LocalDate.

`@FacesConverter(forClass=LocalDate.class)
public LocalDateConverter implements Converter {...}`

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598697/facesconverterforclass-clazz-class-and-pcalendar) I found the answer why Primefaces calendar does not support converter with forClass.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask], [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and improve your question. To cumbersome for anyone to even try to replicate and find a possible cause

Comment: Hello, probably these two links will help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883270/how-to-use-java-time-zoneddatetime-localdatetime-in-pcalendar
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395398/fconvertdatetime-support-for-java8-localdate-localdatetime

Comment: @chaeschuechli thx a lot!